# Ubuntu 14.04 having two postgres server, removing one

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

after installing postgres using apt-get and adding the repo for 9.4, I have two versions, 9.3 and 9.4 running.

How can I remove 9.3? apt-get purge removes both actually.

Thanks ins advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. 
This helped in my case

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3
```

Then remove clusters with the following command.
You may want to back up your data. That wasn't my case.

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.3 main
```

Restart postgres

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```